# Switching between JAVA files - Not XML files

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am doing really important app and i need to ask you, if is there some way, how to switch between java files from one BUTTON with one iD..
Look on this picture for clear: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/811/radab.png/ (i've uploaded it on imageshack because i don't have reputation..

[image]

I am new to the ANDROID developing and i really need your help to the beggining.
Thanks a lot.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java Package name hierarchy is not meant to be a place to hardcode your database of movies into.

Preferably, learn to use SQLite for keeping that kind of data. Don't even bother using XML in this case.

Take a look at this [tutorial.](http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-sqlite-database-example)

Comment: Well...okay, i've just tryed that :D i thought it would be possible

Comment: Please see the tutorial link I've just added.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! I will look on it and try to learn how to use it...
thanks for the tutorial, and for your help.